# Should I url encode a query string parameter that's a URL?

Tags: url, urlencode

Just say I have the following url that has a query string parameter that's an url:

http://www.someSite.com?next=http://www.anotherSite.com?test=1&test=2

**Should I url encode the `next` parameter? If I do, who's responsible for decoding it - the web browser, or my web app?**

The reason I ask is I see lots of big sites that do things like the following

http://www.someSite.com?next=http://www.anotherSite.com/another/url

In the above, they don't bother encoding the `next` parameter because I'm guessing, they know it doesn't have any query string parameters itself. Is this ok to do if my `next` url doesn't include any query string parameters as well?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.4):

> The query component is indicated by the first question mark ("?")
> character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character or by the
> end of the URI.

So the following URI is valid:

http://www.example.com?next=http://www.example.com

The [following excerpt from the RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.4) makes this clear:

> ... as query components are often used to carry identifying
> information in the form of "key=value" pairs and one frequently used
> value is a reference to another URI, it is sometimes better for
> usability to avoid percent-encoding those characters.

It is worth noting that RFC 3986 makes RFC 2396 obsolete.

Comment: What if the `next` URI itself has query parameters? Should just those be encoded? Or the whole URI?

Answer (score 21):

[RFC 2396 sec. 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2) says that you should URL-encode those symbols anywhere where they're not used for their explicit meanings; i.e. you should always form `targetUrl + '?next=' + urlencode(nextURL)`.

The web browser does not 'decode' those parameters at all; the browser doesn't know anything about the parameters but just passes along the string. A query string of the form `http://www.example.com/path/to/query?param1=value&param2=value2` is GET-requested by the browser as:

```
GET /path/to/query?param1=value&param2=value2 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
(other headers follow)
```

On the backend, you'll need to parse the results. I think PHP's `$_REQUEST` array will have already done this for you; in other languages you'll want to split over the first `?` character, then split over the `&` characters, then split over the first `=` character, then urldecode both the name and the value.

Comment: RFC 3986 makes RFC 2396 obsolete. Perhaps this answer needs updating.